# Un-expected output from is_numeric / foreach routine

Tags: php, foreach

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php.

Example #1 is_numeric().

Why does the Example #1 routine output 1337 4 times instead of 1 time?  My expectation is the routine would ouput the other 3 numeric values that follow 1337.  Even if I re-arrange the order of the elements it still outputs 1337 4 times.  I understand hex and binary values are not allowed, but why does the routine output 1337 for those values.  Also, if I change 1337 to 01337 the ouput is 735.

Why these confusing outputs?

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42", 1337, 0x539, 02471, 0b10100111001, 1238.443e2, "not numeric",
    array(), 9.1, null
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo var_export($element, true) . " is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo var_export($element, true) . " is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>

Output:
'42' is numeric
1337 is numeric
1337 is numeric
1337 is numeric
1337 is numeric
123844.300000000002910383045673370361328125 is numeric
'not numeric' is NOT numeric
array () is NOT numeric
9.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 is numeric    
NULL is NOT numeric
```

Comment: Decimal does not count as numeric in this case

Comment: PHP will always default numeric output to be in decimal.  Doesn't matter how you create them, they are just numbers internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Base-N notation syntax

*which you had to know to pull this off*

#### Hexadecimal

A number prefixed with `0x` will be interpreted as base-16

#### Octtal

A number prefixed with `0` will be interpreted as base-8

#### Binary

A number prefixed with `0b` will be interpreted as base-2

#### Conversion to Decimal

- `1337` base10 (base10 value: 1337)
- `0x539` base16 (base10 value: 1337)
- `02471` base8 (base10 value: 1337)
- `0b10100111001` base2 (base10 value: 1337)

## Numbers in strings are always shown in base-10

Converting these numbers to a string, as with var_export, will convert them to base-10, unless you use `number_format`.

Comment: Got it.  All of these values equate to decimal 1337:  1337, 0x539, 02471, 0b10100111001 and php defaults to decimal output.  That makes sense.  Also, if I put 0 in front of 1337 then 1337 is converted to octal so the output of octal 01337 is 735.       Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dustin, you got it.

Comment: I knew th 0x was hex, 0b was binary.  I didn't know a leading 0 would convert a number to octal in php.  I didn't know is_numeric() converted to decimal (don't see that in the manual either).  But mostly, it didn't occured to me to convert these values to decimal to see determine if they were all the same.  I should have, because 40 years ago I did a great deal of assembly language programming.  (that was before C, C++, Pascal, php.  About all that existed back then was Fortran.  At least now it makes sense.

Comment: @Dustin, that's some comedic irony. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because that is your values.

For example, if you start a number with a zero, it is means, this number is in octal number system. `02471 = 1337` in decimal number system. The other is the hexa, the remaining the binary.